# Crystal Reports .NET - Column data repeated

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

In the development PC Crystal report is perfect show the layout, but when I'm moving it to another machine the data of the last 3 columns are exactly the same from the fourth to the end column.

The application is a standalone .NET WPF application along with the .rpt report files.

I have tried rebuild and new installation as well as reboot of the machine. Database used is the same in both cases.

Comment: for column are you use subreport or else, please explain

Comment: @Ajay2707 no. It's just a single table report

Comment: can you add your screen shot with new and old layout. Also your crystal report layout. What I suggest open report , database menu -> update datasource.

Comment: It happened to me in the following scenario. The data source was a .NET DataSet. The XSD schema was different from the DataSet schema. If you are using a DataSet, double check all the column names and types.